# OSGI: classloading and inheritance

Tags: inheritance, osgi, classloader

I have following class hierarchy

[image]

`parent` and `child1` declared in `bundle_1`. `child2` declared in `bundle_2`

Which classloader `child2` will use for loading super class ?

Answer (score 1):

In OSGi you have one ClassLoader per bundle. When loading a class the ClassLoader will first look into the Import-Package statements of the bundle. If the class is from an imported package then the loading is delegated to the ClassLoader of the bundle that offers the package. If none of these matches then the bundle will try to load the class from its own classes. (This is simplified a bit but should be enough for your case).

So the parent and child1 classes will be loaded by the ClassLoader of bundle_1 and child2 will be loaded by the ClassLoader of bundle_2.

One further thing to keep in mind. Every class in java stores the ClassLoader that created this class in "class".getClassLoader(). So this allows you to easily check what really happens. Simply instantiate child1 and child2 and print the ClassLoaders.

Another thing that relates to this is that if you use new "Classname"() inside the code of a class A then this will trigger the ClassLoader that loaded class A. (Which might then delegate of course).

Comment: Does Parent class will load twice?

Comment: No. As the classloading is delegated the classloader of bundle1 will know it already loaded parent.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that a class is uniquely identified by the class name and the class loader by which the class is loaded, `parent` and `child1` must be loaded by the class loader of `bundle_1`. `child2` will be loaded by the class loader of `bundle_2`.

Comment: but super constructor of child2 will invoke on bundle_1 ?

Comment: Your question does not give enough information. What packages are these classes in? What packages are actually exported and imported by the bundles? Also, invocation implies you are talking about threads. Threads do not belong to bundles.

Comment: @gstackoverflow: constructor invocation has actually limited relation to class loading. You need to clarify what you mean with "super constructor of child2 will invoke on bundle_1" or better: your reason for asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @Arie van Wijngaarden Does Parent class will load twice?